# filter by two conditions after a group by

Tags: python, pandas

I am willing to filter the ids which have SMS and Phone in the `type` column and whenever `login_method` is equal to `resend`

```
df

id    type   login_method
 1     SMS         resend
 1     SMS       complete
 2   phone         resend
 2     SMS         resend
 2     SMS          start
 3   phone         resend
 3   phone          start
 3   phone       complete
 3     SMS           nice
```

expected result

```
df
    id    type   login_method
 1     SMS         resend
 1     SMS       complete
 3   phone         resend
 3   phone          start
 3   phone       complete
 3     SMS           nice
```

In this case only id 2 have phone and SMS in the login method equal to resend

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? What is your output? Do you get any error(s)?

Comment: do you think `login_method is NOT equal to resend` ?

Comment: that would give my expected value. But the problem  is an illustrative example, my dataframe could have another value for login_method which is not equal to resend

Comment: I am confused because group 2 have `resend` values in sample data. It is wrong sample?

Comment: there i edit my sample to show what i was meaning. I want to drop ID 2 which has in their resend code phone and SMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
v = ['SMS','phone']
#first filter only valuse by list
df = df[df['type'].isin(v)]

#get id where are all values per groups with resend
m1 = df['login_method'] == 'resend'
s = df[m1].drop_duplicates(['id','type']).groupby('id')['type'].nunique() != len(v)

#filtering by ids
df1 = df[df['id'].isin(s.index[s])]
print (df1)
   id   type login_method
0   1    SMS       resend
1   1    SMS     complete
4   3  phone       resend
5   3  phone        start
6   3  phone     complete
7   3    SMS         nice
```